# How do you analytically show the following expression is negative?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

The expression in question is:

$$
e^{2h(x+1)}(m-1)-me^{2h}+e^{h(1+x+y)}((1 - (-1 + 2 m) h (-1 + x + y))
$$

Graphing, it appears that this expression is always negative as long as $1>m>0$, and $y\neq x-1$. While I only need to show this for $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$ and $h>0$, these don't seem to matter with respect to the expression being negative. Any tips or tricks would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That expression definitely isn't negative for all $x, y, h$, but it does appear to be for $0 < x,y < 1$ and $h >0$. The expression gets a little simpler if you use $1-y$ instead of $y$ (which is still in $(0,1)$), and even simpler if you use $hx$ and $h(1-y)$ as variables.

Comment: Another tip: you're going to need to use the fact that $\exp(z) - 1 - z > 0$ for all $z\in \mathbb R$.